# Check string and only wrap words NOT already wrapped?

Tags: jquery

I hve the following HTML string:

`<span class="class1">Hello</span> my <span class="class1">name</span> is Mads.`

Is it possible to detect the words 'my', 'is' and 'Mads' and wrap those words in a string who is not already part of a span tag?

So it becomes

`<span class="class1">Hello</span> <span class="class1">my</span> <span class="class1">name</span> <span class="class1">is</span> <span class="class1">Mads.</span>`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Loop through the child nodes, and replace the text node using DOM (no jQuery).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right,

I have cracked it - although it may not be the prettiest code you guys have seen.

The html spans are updated on -blur event (when you click outside the div editable field).

[a link to jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/fzMZs/)!

Comment: It is good practice to vote on the answers to your question if they were helpful in the arrival of your solution.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

HTML:

```
<div id="parent">
    <span class="class1">Hello</span> my <span class="class1">name</span> is Mads.
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#parent').contents().filter(function() {
        return this.nodeName == '#text';
    }).replaceWith(function(){
        return this.nodeValue.replace(/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/g, '<span class="class1">$1</span>');
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/CDe5j/

The code above takes the `#parent` object and then uses [`contents()`](http://api.jquery.com/contents/) to get the children within.  It then applies the [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) method, which tests the supplied selector against each element and all of the elements matching the selector will be selected.  Once only the text elements, non-spans, are selected, the [replaceWith()](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/) method is used to ensure that each individual word is wrapped as a span element, via a regex for all alpha-numberical characters, underscore, and hyphen.  You can view additional information on Regular Expresions [here](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/redev2.shtml).

Comment: Very close to what I want it to do :-) However it returns: `**<span class="class1"></span>**<span class="class1">Hello</span><span class="class1"> my </span><span class="class1">name</span>**<span class="class1"> is Mads.</span>**`. Then it does not wrap EACH word not wrapped? As it wrappes the entire substring "is Mads"?

Comment: I need each word in html string not having a span arount it, have a span around it. Hope this makes sense?

Comment: @MadsChristianSidenius - Updated answer to account for the substrings.

Answer (score 1):

If you get the parent element you can use the jQuery objects text() function to get the text. You can the use split(" ") to create an Array and iterate over it to wrap each token in a tag.

Comment: Yes that is true, but I enter a text into a div editable area - and when I click an "edit" button I need to wrap span tags + class="class1" around those words which does not already have a spanwrapped around them.

Answer (score 1):

First, parse the HTML string into the DOM by putting it into a DIV element, like so:

```
<div id="wrap">
   <span class="class1">Hello</span> my <span class="class1">name</span> is Mads.
</div>
```

Now, execute this code:

```
var $wrap = $( '#wrap' );

$wrap.contents().filter(function () {
    return this.nodeType === 3 && $.trim( this.data );
}).replaceWith(function () {
    return this.data.replace( /(\w+)/g, '<span class="class1">$1</span>' );
});
```

After the above code ran, you can retrieve the resulting string like so:

```
var result = $wrap.html();
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/Rhpaa/1/

I'm using `/(\w+)/` to match a word. I'm not sure how reliable it is. If it doesn't work reliably, try to find a more reliable word-matching regular expression on SO.